# Right justify text in Devexpress TextEdit and show text from the end

Tags: devexpress, textedit

I would like to right justify text and show text from the end.
For example: 
say textEdit1 has filepath as its content
"C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\xxx\CODE\test\inner test\another\another\filename.sdfx"

If the entire text is not visible in the text edit then show text from the end so that filename is always visible.

I know how to right justify text but not sure about the second part. Any help highly appreciated.[image]

In the above image the filepath is too long to be shown fully so I would like to show the path from the end so that **filename** is always visible. Hope I made myself clear.

I am using Devexpress 11.2 for Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "show text from end"? Also, which DecExpress control suite are you using ASP.NET? Can you post some code?

Comment: What code would you like? right justify is set in options like this:  TextEdit.Properties.Appearance.TextOptions.HAlignment = Far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which is to do with SelectionStart as stated above but it has to be done after the TextEdit is completely loaded.

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);

    textEdit1.Text = @"C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\xxx\CODE\test\inner test\another\another\filename.xxx";
    textEdit1.SelectionStart = textEdit1.Text.Length;
}
```

All thanks to Devexpress.

Answer (score 0):

I think the caret position in the editor can be set using the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties. After that, all you have to do is to implement both `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events so that even when there is no focus, the end of the text is shown.

More details [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q330023).